# OpenCV 3 SURF feature detection

Tags: c++, c, opencv, visual-studio-2012, surf

I am trying to do a simple surf feature detection. 
The problem is that during the execution I have two Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Errors with only the use of the detect method :

> Debug Assertion Failed ! 
>  Program:
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120D.dll 
>  File : C:\Program Files
>   (x86\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vector 
>  Line: 240
>
> Expression : vector iterators incompatible

And

> Debug Assertion Failed ! 
>  Program:
>   C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\Debug\opencv_xfeatures2d300d.dll 
>  File : C:\Program Files
>   (x86\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vector 
>  Line: 241
>
> Expression : "Standard C++ Libraries Invalid Argument" && 0

This is the code :

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/ocl.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"

#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace xfeatures2d;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    // Read image
    Mat img1 = imread("box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img2 = imread("box_in_scene.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (img1.empty() || img2.empty())
    {
        printf("Images non lisibles \n");
        return -1;
    }

    // detecting keypoints

    int hessian = 800;

    Ptr<SURF> surf = SURF::create(hessian);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;

    surf->detect(img1, keypoints1);
    surf->detect(img2, keypoints2);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```